# What are the alcohol free beers?

Tags: non-alcoholic

I drink beer occasionally. So far I have only drank alcoholic ones. Now I need to know whether alcohol-free beers exist or not. If so, what are their brand names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common brands off the top of my head are:

- St Pauli N.A.
- O'Doul's
- Kalibur
- Clausthaler

There are actually plenty of others, a few of the major brewers like Miller and Coors also produce a non-alcoholic version and a few other German brands you might be able to find come in non-alcoholic.

Be forewarned that none of them are generally regarded as "good" when compared to full-strength beer.

If your interest is just to not get completely obliterated after drinking several beers, I'd investigate a category called "Session" beers, which are regular beers brewed without artificially removing any alcohol but are designed to be flavorful at 3-4% ABV rather than the common 5-6%+ that many craft beers tend to be.  Full Sail session lager, Stone's Go To IPA, and Founder's All Day IPA should be pretty easy to find, but investigate more local and regional breweries to see if they make any.

Answer (score 0):

BITBURGER GERMAN 100% Alcohol-free

Tastes like beer.
Made full strength then all alcohol extracted.